# HiveException: Failed to create spark client

Tags: apache-spark, hivecontext

1)I have created a sql file where we are collecting the data from two different hive table and Inserting into a single Hive table,

2) we are invoking  this SQL file using shell script

3)Sample Spark Setting:

```
SET hive.execution.engine=spark;
SET spark.master=yarn-cluster;
SET spark.app.name="ABC_${hiveconf:PRC_DT}_${hiveconf:JOB_ID}";
--SET spark.driver.memory=8g;
--SET spark.executor.memory=8g;
SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode = nonstrict;
SET hive.stats.fetch.column.stats=true;
SET hive.optimize.index.filter=true;
Set hive.map.aggr=true;
Set hive.exec.parallel=true;SET spark.executor.cores=5;
SET hive.prewarm.enabled=true;
SET hive.spark.client.future.timeout=900;
SET hive.spark.client.server.connect.timeout=100000;
```

4)sample Hive Query:

```
insert OVERWRITE table ABC (a,b,c) select * from XYZ
from ${hiveconf:SCHEMA_NAME}.${hiveconf:TABLE_NAME}
where JOB_ID = '${hiveconf:JOB_ID}'
```

5)Sample Script:

```
hive -f $PARENTDIR/sql/test.sql --hiveconf SCHEMA_NAME=ABC --hiveconf TABLE_NAME=AB1 --hiveconf PRC_DT=${PRC_DT} --hiveconf JOB_ID=${JOB_ID} 
hive -f $PARENTDIR/sql/test.sql --hiveconf SCHEMA_NAME=ABC --hiveconf TABLE_NAME=AB2 --hiveconf PRC_DT=${PRC_DT} --hiveconf JOB_ID=${JOB_ID} 

Error:
2016-08-24 17:30:05,651 WARN  [main] mapreduce.TableMapReduceUtil: The hbase-prefix-tree module jar containing PrefixTreeCodec is not present.  Continuing without it.

Logging initialized using configuration in jar:file:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.7.2-1.cdh5.7.2.p0.18/jars/hive-common-1.1.0-cdh5.7.2.jar!/hive-log4j.properties
FAILED: SemanticException Failed to get a spark session: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Failed to create spark client.
```

Comment: put the command and err message in ```code block```, it will help you make your question easier to understand :)

Comment: @sel-fish new to this learning the tricks

Answer (score 1):

It's erroring because you're not getting an ApplicationMaster assigned prior to timing out.  Increase the following parameter (defaults to 90000ms, you have it set to 100000ms above):

```
set hive.spark.client.server.connect.timeout=300000ms;
```